# Slick slider: adding space in between images shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

Maybe I am just being ridiculous and this is a simple thing but I am trying to add spacing in between the images shown using slick slider.

The JS

```
$('.slider').slick({ 
    infinite: true, 
    speed: 700, 
    arrows: true, 
    slidesToShow: 2, 
    slidesToScroll: 2, 
    dots: false, 
    responsive: [ { settings: "unslick" ## Heading ##}, ] 
});
```

And my attempt at adding the space with css:

```
.slick-slide { 
    &:nth-of-type(odd){ 
        padding-left:0px; 
        padding-right:100px; 
    } 
    &:nth-of-type(even){ 
        padding-right:0px; 
        padding-left:100px; 
    } 
}
```

If there is anyone who can help that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of applying properties to the `.slick-slide` selector directly, you should prefer apply them to a child element.

For example, if the HTML code is,

```
<div class="slider">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
</div>
```

then the SASS should be,

```
.slick-slide { 
  h3{
    background: red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Note that the `margin` here is causing the required spacing. 
Check out the [codepen](https://codepen.io/dsaket/pen/QgZLVK) I have created for you to have better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, because slick start first item on screen with attribute `data-slick-index="0"` data by 0

```
.slick-slide {
   margin-left:20px;
}

.slick-list [data-slick-index="0"] {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
```